# Sorting a list of tuples, where each tuple consists of a string and a set

Tags: python, sorting, set, tuples

I would like to take my list of tuples, where each tuple consists of a string and a set, and rearrange it so that it is sorted by the string with most entries in it's associated set first.

Pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: Sample input / output would be invaluable in attempting to help you.  Also, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Thanks for the link, I'm new to this whole thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a key function to `list.sort()`:

```
my_list = [("a", set([1, 2, 3])), 
           ("b", set([1, 2, 3, 4])),
           ("c", set([1, 2]))]
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)
```

This results in `my_list` being

```
[('b', set([1, 2, 3, 4])), ('a', set([1, 2, 3])), ('c', set([1, 2]))]
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't quite understand how to get it to read what I wanted, perfect answer though.